# Is it possible to convert a String into a List data type?

Tags: string, list, jython, jes

Okay so, my code:

```
def isPalindrome():
  string = requestString("give me a Palendrom!, add spaces between each letter")
  list = string.split()
  print list
  reverseList = list.reverse()
  print reverseList
```

this is unfinished, but the idea is to detect Palindromes, the user is to input a word and, what I want to be able to do is say.

```
if list = reverseList:
  print "yes"
else:
  print "no!"
```

But unfortunately the return from what I have is:

```
======= Loading Progam =======
>>> isPalindrome()
['r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r']
None
>>>
```

My class mates are taking a different approach to this question, but I have a reputation for 'unique' code, so I was hoping this would work.

My question is 
1 is this even possible?
2 is there a better approach to this problem?

Side note, I am very new to this, I am using JES, Jython and this is my first question on stackoverflow, be kind :D

Edit:

```
def isPalindrome2():
  string = requestString("give me a Palindrome, make sure the letters are spaced")
  print string
  reversedString = string[::-1]
  print reversedString

  if string == reversedString:
    print ("this is a Palindrome")
  else:
    print ("this is not a Palindrome")
```

OutPut:

```
>>> isPalindrome2()
r a d a r
r a d a r
this is a Palindrome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[::-1]
```

It should return the string reversed.

Comment: Yes it does! but I guess the tagged question is still unanswered... but this suits my needs so cheers!

Comment: Ho, if you really wand to turn it into a list, you can use `list(string)`.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python